# How to narrow matrix by looking specific elements

Tags: r, string, matrix, vector

Let's consider matrix following:

```
string_vec <- c("huge", "small", "small_very", "something", "big_huge", "big_very", "tremendous")
combinations <- utils::combn(string_vec, 3)
```

It will output matrix containing all combinations of third degree.

I want to take only the combinations which include `"small"` **and** `"small_very"`

And I'm not sure how to do it. I tried code

```
apply(combinations, 2, function(x) x %in% c("small", "small_very"))
```

But it outputs combinations including `"small"` **or** `"small_very"`

Do you know how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one more solution

```r
string_vec <- c("huge", "small", "small_very", "something", "big_huge", "big_very", "tremendous")
combinations <- utils::combn(string_vec, 3)

combinations[, apply(combinations, 2, function(x) sum(x %in% c("small", "small_very"))) == 2]
#>      [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]        
#> [1,] "huge"       "small"      "small"      "small"      "small"     
#> [2,] "small"      "small_very" "small_very" "small_very" "small_very"
#> [3,] "small_very" "something"  "big_huge"   "big_very"   "tremendous"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Check for both conditions to be satisfied separately, "join" together using `&`:

```
combinations[,apply(combinations, 2, FUN = function(x) ("small" %in% x) & ("small_very" %in% x))]

#      [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]        
# [1,] "huge"       "small"      "small"      "small"      "small"     
# [2,] "small"      "small_very" "small_very" "small_very" "small_very"
# [3,] "small_very" "something"  "big_huge"   "big_very"   "tremendous"
```

Comment: Wow so easy! I also thought about `&` but I was using it incorrectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @John if this worked for you, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this

```
combn(subset(string_vec,! string_vec %in% (v <- c("small","small_very"))),1,function(x) c(v,x))
```

which gives

```
     [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]        
[1,] "small"      "small"      "small"      "small"      "small"     
[2,] "small_very" "small_very" "small_very" "small_very" "small_very"
[3,] "huge"       "something"  "big_huge"   "big_very"   "tremendous"
```